# How to Delete from Last letter then work getSelectedText function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to delete last character from a input textbox using JavaScript?
I make this small task Its function is that when we write a letter in the input, it checks the index number of the value in the queue. And we will choose them all
And we will select everyone in the input except the letter we have written.

1. Now I want that when I delete a letter, it will be deleted and the getSelectedText function will be run.
2. And when I press the control button or any other Esc key.
   So let's show all the values in the Array.

HTML Code:

```
<input id="autocomplet" onkeyup="filter(this.value);">
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
var data = document.querySelector('#autocomplet');
var myArray = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];

function filter(letter) {
        var results = [];
        var len = myArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].indexOf(letter) == 0){
       results.push(myArray[i]);
       data.value = results;
       getSelectedText(data,letter);
    }
  }
if((event.keyCode == 46) || (event.keyCode == 8)){
        data.value='';
    }
}
function getSelectedText(data,letter) {
  data = data.value;
  var datalength = data.length; 
  var letterlength = letter.length;
  autocomplet.setSelectionRange(letterlength,datalength);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to remove the `jquery` tag as you are seeking a JavaScript answer.

Comment: If the user enters `c` what should the expected result be?

Comment: C++, coldfusion

Comment: Ok, so how would that get shown in the Text field?

Comment: same as it is C++, coldfusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know If This Helps but here it is.

```js
    var data = document.querySelector('#autocomplet');
    var myArray = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];

    function filter(letter) {
        var results = [];
        var len = myArray.length;
        if ((event.keyCode == 46) || (event.keyCode == 8)) {
            return getSelectedText(data, letter);
            // data.value = '';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].indexOf(letter) == 0) {
                results.push(myArray[i]);
                data.value = results;
                getSelectedText(data, letter);
            }
        }
    }

    function getSelectedText(data, letter) {
        data = data.value;
        var datalength = data.length;
        var letterlength = letter.length;
        autocomplet.setSelectionRange(letterlength, datalength);
    }
```

Comment: Its Not work Correctly.

Comment: I didn't understand your question then, Sorry

Comment: According to this code, when I delete a letter,
 the whole box becomes empty instead of the letter

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input and put it in a string. Then take the lenght of the input and do a for loop which will run one time less than the number of the lenght. After that get letter by letter to reconstruct the phrase in a new variable.

```
let phrase = “your_phrase.”;
let x = 0;
let p2=“”;
let n = 0;
while(true)
{
   if(phrase == null){break;}
   x++
}
x—-; //maybe try to delete this if 1 extra letter deleted.
for(n; n <= x-1;x++)
{
   p2 = p2 - phrase[n];
}
```

Comment: According to this code, when I delete a letter, the whole box becomes empty instead of the letter

Comment: Maybe try to edit for loop.

Comment: I am working on a fix wait 10 mins max. It’s just I am in class and did the code too fast

Comment: I try it but not working

Comment: Finally working sorry for the wait. I could finally try my code in a JavaScript compiler

Comment: or get the length and set the last character to ‘’

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. This is a jQuery example, yet all the same algorithm should apply to JavaScript.

```js
$(function() {
  var myArray = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];

  function checkEntry(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
      resetVal(event.target);
    }
    filter($(event.target).val(), event.target);
  }

  function resetVal(target) {
    var val = $(target).val();
    var sel = window.getSelection().toString();
    window.getSelection().empty();
    console.log("Reset", val, sel);
    $(target).val(val.slice(0, val.length - 1));
  }

  function filter(term, target) {
    var result = [];
    console.log("Filter", term);
    $.each(myArray, function(i, v) {
      if (v.indexOf(term) == 0) {
        result.push(v);
      }
    });
    $(target).val(result.toString());
    getSelectedText($(target).val(), term);
  }

  function getSelectedText(data, letter) {
    console.log("Select", data, letter);
    $("#autocomplet").get(0).setSelectionRange(letter.length, data.length);
  }

  $("#autocomplet").keyup(checkEntry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="autocomplet" type="text" />
```

**Alternate**

Consider the following that uses jQuery UI Autocomplete

```js
$(function() {
  var myArray = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];

  function getSelectedText(target, data, letter) {
    $(target).get(0).setSelectionRange(letter.length, data.length);
  }

  $("#autocomplet").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(myArray, function(index, item) {
        if (item.indexOf(request.term) == 0) {
          results.push(item);
        }
      });
      response(results);
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(e, ui) {
      var cVal = $(this).val();
      var sel = ui.item.label;
      $(this).val(sel);
      getSelectedText(this, sel, cVal);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="autocomplet" type="text" />
```

Resources:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source
- https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: Shows only one value in input. How to get all the valves to show from the match letter

Comment: @MuhammadTufail you mean like this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Yes, but show on input field

Comment: @MuhammadTufail please see the update

Comment: list display on input field and selection function not work

Comment: @MuhammadTufail in my testing, they are working as expected. Please clarify in detail what is not working for you. Please include steps I would take to replicate the issue.

Comment: 1. Dropdown list should not be a show.                                          2. Everything that appears in the dropdown list should appear in the input field.

Comment: @MuhammadTufail should there be any delimiter or separator? What should be highlighted? This is a very confusing request.

Comment: @MuhammadTufail I updated the answer again. Please review the first example that now combines all results into an Array and converts it into a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242998/discussion-between-muhammad-tufail-and-twisty).

Comment: https://youtu.be/BdBulXROv1k

Comment: plz help me in javascript